# Eclipse Plugin: Property Tester (to make a command conditionally visible) is not working the way it is expected

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, command, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP. I defined a popup menu item command. To control the command's visibility, I set a test condition using a property tester. This property tester makes command invisible except the first time opening of the menu. Means if I open the popup menu for first time, that particular command is visible irrespective of the property tester. When I open that menu for second time, it decides the visibility based on property tester. Could anyone explain me why does it happen?

Following is the complete code that I am trying.

Command

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command 
      id="com.eclipse-tips.commandState.alignCommand" 
      name="Align Command"> 
      <state id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState">
      <class class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState">
      <parameter 
            name="default" 
            value="false"> 
      </parameter> 
      <parameter 
            name="persisted" 
            value="false"> 
      </parameter>
      </class>
      </state>
    </command>
    </extension>
```

Handler

```xml
      <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
         <handler
            class="com.gnr.handlers.AlignCommand"
            commandId="com.eclipse-tips.commandState.alignCommand">
       </handler>
       </extension>
```

Menu contribution

```xml
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
        <command
        commandId="com.eclipse-tips.commandState.alignCommand"
        label="Align Command"
        style="toggle">
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="true">
           <with
                 variable="selection">
              <iterate>
                 <adapt
                       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                    <test
                          property="com.gnr.testgen.checkInputFile_Align"
                          value="true">
                    </test>
                 </adapt>
              </iterate>
           </with>
        </visibleWhen>
        </command>
        </menuContribution>
      </extension>
```

Property Tester

```xml
      <extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
        <propertyTester
            class="com.gnr.testgen.UserPropertyTester_Align"
            id="com.gnr.testgen.user.propertyTester_Align"
            namespace="com.gnr.testgen"
            properties="checkInputFile_Align"
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
       </propertyTester>
      </extension>
```

Following is the handler code

```java
    public class AlignCommand extends AbstractHandler {


        @Override
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
            Command command = event.getCommand();

            State state = command.getState(RegistryToggleState.STATE_ID);

            boolean oldValue = ((Boolean) state.getValue()).booleanValue();
            state.setValue(new Boolean(!oldValue));

            return null;
        }   

    }
```

Finally PropertyTester

```java
    public class UserPropertyTester_Align extends PropertyTester {

        public UserPropertyTester_Align() { }

        @Override
        public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, 
        Object expectedValue) {

            return false;
        }

    }
```

Here, you can see, property tester is returning 'false'. It means command should not be visible, but it does not happen. First time when I open the popup menu, the command is visible and second time when I open the popup menu, the command is not visible.

Comment: Is the property testing actually being run? Make sure you are running with the `-clean` option to make sure the extensions registry is updated each time you test.

Comment: @greg-449 This property tester works fine except the first time. From second time onward, command becomes invisible. I tried -clean option, but it could not help me out.

Comment: This code seems to work fine testing here (except that the handler crashes because the State is not defined).

Comment: @greg-449 Now, state is defined.